# How to hide an html element when clicked outside

Tags: angular

I want to know a way in which when clicked outside an html element(in my case , please see my code), the tooltip should hide. I don't want to use 'ng-clicked-outisde' library.

Is there a way in which we can achieve it.

Here is the link of my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b61t71

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HostListener` and `ViewChild` like this

```
@ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip: ElementRef;

  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if (this.tooltip) {
      if (!this.tooltip.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
        this.clickHover = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

and update html file

```
<div #tooltip class="tooltip" (click)="clickHover = true">Click me!
  <span  [style.display]="clickHover ? 'block':'none'" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrbzsh)

Comment: Thanks @ahmeticat, that's the Angular way! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could add an overlay like this :

In .html :

```html
<div class="overlay" *ngIf="clickHover" (click)="clickHover = false"></div>
<div class="tooltip" (click)="clickHover = true">Click me!
  <span *ngIf="clickHover" class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

in .css :

```css
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Actually I know that's not the best solution. But it do the job if you don't have a big component :)

Answer (score 0):

Bind event on a root element of your component or on document element or on the wrapper of your document and handle cases:

1. click on your element
2. click on other elements

Comment: Thanks @Akif for the answer.